# Pandas dataframe sum same keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi i want to compare same keys of a pandas dataframe

dataframe

|  | car | values(dict) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | audi | {'colour': 'black', 'PS': '230', 'owner': 'peter'} |
| 1 | audi | {'owner': 'fred', 'colour': 'black', 'PS': '230', 'number': '155555'} |
| 2 | ford | {'windows': 'yes', 'PS': '230', 'owner': 'pam'} |
| 3 | bmw | {'colour': 'black', 'windows': 'yes', 'owner': 'peter', 'doors': '5'} |

|  | colour | owner | PS | number | windows | doors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| audi | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| ford | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| bmw | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

is there any efficient solution

Comment: Just curious, how did you create your dataframe?

Comment: from a json file

Comment: You may be able to read the data with `json_normalize` and have better datastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `apply(pd.Series)` expands a **dict** into columns
- `join()` this back to original DF without **dict** column
- simple `groupby().count()` to get results you want

```
df.loc[:,"car"].to_frame().join(df["values(dict)"].apply(pd.Series)).groupby("car",as_index=False).count()
```

|  | car | colour | PS | owner | number | windows | doors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | audi | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | bmw | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | ford | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |